# MetricFilterAutoConfiguration throwing Exception with spring-boot-legacy on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, spring-boot

I've tried the following combos and can't get rid of this error:

- Spring Boot 1.1.6 RELEASE and Spring 4.0.7
- Spring Boot 1.2.0 RC1 and Spring 4.1.2
- Declared a custom DispatcherServlet with event publication disabled

  `@Bean(name = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
  public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
      DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
      dispatcherServlet.setPublishEvents(false);
      return dispatcherServlet;
  }`

This is similar to [Exception from running spring-boot-legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797222/exception-from-running-spring-boot-legacy) but that issue has been fixed and the exception that I am getting now does not appear to be covered by the Spring Bug (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12151).

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.getStatus(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:135)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:94)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

OS: OS X 10.10
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Spring Boot legacy cloned and built from: https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy

Comment: This appears to be related to spring-boot-actuator because after finally removing: compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}") this issue went away. I would like to know a workaround that will let me use the actuator without seeing this exception.

Comment: Are you using the spring-boot-legacy library? What version and where did you get it?

Comment: Yes. Spring Boot legacy cloned and built from: https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy

Answer (score 0):

Here is what was causing the issue:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
compile files('lib/spring-boot-legacy.jar')
```

Here is what fixes the issue:

```
compile files('lib/spring-boot-legacy.jar')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
```

Unfortunately, I didn't have enough understanding of how everything was connected to figure this out quickly via the stacktraces.